# Submit. Кнопки и запросы.

Tags: php, html

Есть, к примеру, определенный **submit**, на который должен среагировать определенный **запрос** при нажатии.

Пример **submit**:

```
<input type="submit" name="search" value="Поиск">
```

Пример **запроса**:

```
mysql_query("select * from `$_GET[table]` where `ФИО` like '%$_GET[fio]%'");
```

Как их связать? Неужели прибегать к If'ам?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понимаю, то вам нужно либо вешать на каждую сабмит кнопку функцию при онклик и через асинхронный запрос делать то, что вам нужно с базой, либо же да, после отправки формы ставить `if (isset($_GET['search'])) { ... //запрос и все остальное .. }`.

Comment: Ага, что-то вроде этого, спасибо.